# How does UISlider call setValue() method before self becomes available?

Tags: swift

I'm subclassing `UIControl` to make a custom slider as an exercise in learning `UIKit`. The `setValue(value:)` method takes a float/double argument and animates the slider to that value. However, if the slider is not instantiated with an explicit frame, but instead sized using constraints, the `setValue()` method cannot be called without crashing as it requires the intrinsic width of the slider to determine where to animate the slider's thumb.

What would the proper strategy be to make sure an optional property (in this case, the width of `self`) becomes available before a method that has already been called is fully executed?

```
func addSlider() {

    slider.minimumValue = 0
    slider.maximumValue = 42
    slider.setValue(39)
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderAction(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(slider)
    slider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    slider.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -64).isActive = true

}
```

The problem is that `slider.setValue(39)` requires the slider's width to make the calculation.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    superWidth = rect.width
    drawTrack()
    drawThumb()

}

...

func setValue(_ value: Float) {

    let thumbX = CGFloat(value / maximumValue!) * (superWidth - thumbDimension)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { [weak self] in
        self?.thumbLayer.frame.origin.x = thumbX
    })

}
```

Comment: Can you please show a bit of your code which is crashing? It's difficult to guess a solution without knowing as to how you're setting up the slider.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way is

```
guard let widthValue = width else { return }
// use widthValue
```

Or

```
if let widthValue = width {
    // use widthValue
}
```

Both are good and have merit. The first gives you a little more control with statement. And it’s more what you’re looking for. If width doesn’t exist, return. If we unwrap widthValue then use it.

Comment: Problem is I never have a width value until Autolayout produces it, there is no default to fall back on.

Comment: I don’t think you want a default. If you’re looking for doing this at the right time... you need to call setValue after viewdidload(). Otherwise just guard against nil

Comment: Also you may look into calling view.layoutIfNeeded() after activating your constraints.

Comment: And if you’re using the storyboard, it’s much easier and better practice to make these constraints outlets as well

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was create a conditional statement that stores `value` (the argument) in an instance property if the intrinsic width is not available:

```
@objc func setValue(_ value: Float) {

    if superWidth != nil {

        let thumbX = CGFloat(value / maximumValue!) * (superWidth - thumbDimension)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.thumbLayer.frame.origin.x = thumbX
        })

    } else {

        valueToBeSet = value

    }

}
```

And then re-called the method once the width was set:

```
var superWidth: CGFloat! {
    didSet {
        if valueToBeSet != nil {
            setValue(valueToBeSet!)
            valueToBeSet = nil
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but is this an acceptable practice?